# Show that the function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+x)}$ is defined, continuous and differentiable

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity

Show that the function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+x)}$ is defined, continuous and differentiable on $[0;+\infty)$

I get that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+x)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\cdot(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+x})=\frac{1}{x}$. Hence we get that $f(x)$ is defined for any $x \neq 0$, but it's not continuous. Can anyone tell me that I did wrong? Thank you so much.

Comment: What is your domain for $f$?

Comment: The domain of $f$ is $R$, I think. This is a problem from my teacher, but he didn't mention its domain.

Comment: Sorry, its domain is $[0,+\infty)$, I forgot it. Excuse me.

Comment: As a sidenote (not that it's relevant to solving the problem at hand): the series here can be written $\frac{\psi^{(0)}(x+1)+\gamma}{x}$ where $\psi$ is known as the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function). If $x$ is an integer this reduces to $\frac{1 + \frac{1}{2} +\ldots + \frac{1}{x}}{x} = \frac{H_x}{x}$ where $H_x$ is the [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your series is not defined if $x$ is a negative integer. Second, while it is true that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+x)} = \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + x} \right)$ (as long as $x$ is not a non-negative integer), your series is not a telescopic series and so there's no reason that it will converge to $\frac{1}{x}$.

Instead, you can argue that on any interval of the form $[-k, k] \setminus \{ -1, \dots, -k \}$ and for $n > k$ you have a bound of the form

$$ \left| \frac{1}{n(n+x)} \right| = \frac{1}{n|n+x|} \leq \frac{1}{n(n - k)}   $$

and since the right-hand side converges, by the Wierstrass $M$-test you get that $f$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1, -2, \dots \}$.

If you differentiate $f$ formally, you obtain the series $-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+x)^2}$ which also converges absolutely on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ -1, -2, \dots \}$ by the Wierstrass $M$-test and this shows that $f$ is indeed differentiable with derivative given by $f'(x) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+x)^2}$.

Comment: I've edited the domain of $f$ in my question. Thank you so much, I see it now. :D